# Angularjs how to insert html elements with ng binding using directive function with parameters

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My idea is to dynamically add html structure with ng-binding onto existing javasctript object. We should implement app called WorkflowManagementSystem, that manage workflows in company. And we should be able to show instantly workflow user is creating at the time. User should have option to make parallel branches so the problem is with displaying those branches. And another issue is number of blocks in those parallel branches dont have to be equal. (for instance in left branch would be one block and in right branch 3 blocks)

Now it is looking like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCmxD.jpg)

and when it is parallel it should be:
[parallel branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx5RU.jpg)

I would like to inject html structure bellow into html view `<addDiv></addDiv>` (structure bellow is just for normal branch at the moment). If it is normal branch it should inject different html structure then if it is parallel.  When I am calling `vm.addNormalDiv(vm.normalNum);`, it says: "vm.addNormalDiv is not a function". I suppose I got different scope in controller and in directive, but I do not know how to solve it.

I am newbie in angularjs and dont know if it is right approach of implementing this idea. Could you please help me?

I have angular controller looking like:

```
    (function () {
"use strict";

// Getting existing module
angular.module("app-workflow", [])
    .controller("workflowController", workflowController)
.directive("addDiv", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.addNormalDiv = function (val) {
                elm.after($compile('<addDiv>'
                    + '<div ng-repeat="block in vm.normalBlocks['+val+']" class="form-group row block">'
                +'<div class="col-lg-6">'
                    +'<label class="control-label">Název bloku</label>'
                    +'<div>'
                        +'<span class="form-control">{{block.name}}</span>'
                    +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
                +'<div class="col-lg-6">'
                    +'<label class="control-label">Popis bloku</label>'
                    +'<div>'
                        +'<span class="form-control">{{block.description}}</span>'
                    +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
                +'<div class="col-lg-6">'
                    +'<label class="control-label">Výchozí uživatel</label>'
                    +'<div>'
                        +'<span class="form-control">{{block.worker.name}}</span>'
                    +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
                +'<div class="col-lg-6">'
                    +'<label class="control-label">Typ bloku</label>'
                    +'<div>'
                        +'<span class="form-control">{{block.blockType.name}}</span>'
                    +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
            +'</div>'
            + '</addDiv>')(scope));
            }
        }
    };
});


function workflowController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.normalNum = 0;
       vm.addNormalDiv(vm.normalNum); 
    }
})();
```

and html view:

```
<div ng-controller="workflowController as vm">
        <addDiv>

        </addDiv>
</div>
```